# copying big files to a usb stick slows down tremendously after the first file

Tags: usb-drive, troubleshooting

I'm trying to copy multiple 1GB+ files to a USB stick but after two transfers the subsequent transfers get very slow, I tried this with 2 different sticks. For instance I have a usb 3.0 stick and the first two files copy at a rate of 200mb/s but the third file slows down so tremendously that I'm forced to stop and remount the stick to regain a healthy transfer rate.

Any idea what might be happening ?

Comment: May be caching is speeding-up the first one or two. If you have some free RAM, then the copy command can make progress, but is only copying to cache in RAM, the operating system lags behind at the speed of the USB device, copying it to the USB. This allows snappy operation for small-ish files. But when the cache is full, it all slows-down.

Comment: With the computer relatively idle, do `sync; cp …; time sync` (but the relevant copy command in place of the ellipses. What output do you get?

Comment: @richard thanks you were right  the sync command shows that the transfer takes 2min consistently for similarly sized files when without sync it takes few secs for the first file and longer and longer for subsequent transfers.